# How to handle no data alert in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I am using CnosDB + Grafana to collect some system info (CPU, memory) according to the [doc](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/versatility/visualization/grafana.html). If everything goes well, there will be data all the time. However, if the system down, there would be NO DATA piping into the CnosDB database instance. Is there [any function](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/reference/sql.html) I could make use of to detect the NO DATA?

[image]

I tried the [Grafana way](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/state-and-health/#special-alerts-for-nodata-and-error) and it looks good:

> NoData    No data has been received for the configured time window.

I would like to know the CnosDB way as I would like to script it if there is no visualization tool.
The InfluxQL way is:

```
SELECT derivative(usage_idle) FROM CPU WHERE time > now() - 1h
```

If the derivative of above field is zero, it indicates that there is no change in the data, which can be an indication of NO DATA. I can then use this information in the alerting or processing logic.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) what you've written so far. Is there some reason that a polling query which compares biggest timestamp with current clock would not suit your needs?